# Is it possible to configure Postgres to show string values as quoted strings in interactive mode?

Tags: postgresql

Essentially, I want to be able to see trailing spaces and blank values easily when I am working from the command line.

I would like interactive Postgres to show strings as quoted values all the time in the results from queries that I run from the command line.

Is that possible?

I would like the usual output of

```
mydb => select * from abc;
a | b | c
--|---|--
0 |   | t
1 | t | f
```

to look like:

```
mydb => select * from abc;
a |  b  | c
--|-----|--
0 | ' ' | t
1 | 't' | f
```

Comment: This depends on the client you are using - by "interactive mode", do you mean the `psql` command-line client? Or are you using some other client such as phpPgAdmin or pgAdmin III?

Comment: I mean the command line client.

Comment: There are various output options listed on [the documentation for `psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html) (see under `\pset` for most of them), but I can't at a glance see one for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the `quote_literal` function is what you need. See the [String Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) doc.

But that function may do more than you ask. You could write a similar function yourself in [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) to wrap any passed value in quotes.

Comment: I suppose, but how would I apply that in the .psqrc configuration to show strings as quoted in the results from queries on the command line?